# DIV onclick not working after container DIV display set to none then back to inline

Tags: javascript

I have created a mini version of the page I am having problems with; as I do to get rid of as much code as possible that may be  causing the problem.

The first code as  designed....  The second code with the Day DIV not hidden and the javascript to change display states commented out. Click on a calendar day of the month should take you to that days scheduled appointments.  Then cliching back to Months click on the other day should take you back to Day tab with that days appointments.

The first code that does not work throws no errors in Apache Error log or Browser Javascript console.

First Code Example:

```
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
/*************************************************************************
******** Page ************************************************************
*************************************************************************/
.Tab
{
  position: relative;
}
.TabBttn
{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #4DCBEF;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left ;
}
.TabBttn:hover
{
  background-color: #85FFD6;
}
.TabBttn:focus
{
  background-color: #85FFD6;
}
.CurBttn
{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #EBF0FA;
  color: #470047;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left ;
}
#C_Debug
{
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
  max-height: 800px;
  padding: 6px 12px 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
}

/*************************************************************************
******** Month ***********************************************************
*************************************************************************/
.CalendarDIV
{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
.Mnth
{
  background-color: #6699FF;
  color: #000;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Cell
{
  float: left; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 53px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
}
.Head
{
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Clr
{
  clear: both;
}
.Day
{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000 ;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Not
{
  background-color: #DCE0E0;
}
.Today
{
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.First
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #005CE6;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Last
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #007A00;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Open
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #FFFF99;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Closed
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #FF9999;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
//====== Main Page ====================================
var aBtn = new Array() ;
var aTab = new Array() ;
var nCur = 0 ;

//====== Day ==========================================
var oMonthCurDay = null ;
var sMonthCurDay = null ;

//====== Day ==========================================
var oDayDate = null ;

window.onload = function ()
{
  //====== Main Page ====================================
  aBtn[ 0 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn0'  ) ; 
  aBtn[ 1 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn1'  ) ;
  aBtn[ 2 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn2'  ) ;
  aBtn[ 3 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn3'  ) ;
  aTab[ 0 ] = document.getElementById( 'Months' ) ; 
  aTab[ 1 ] = document.getElementById( 'Day'    ) ;
  aTab[ 2 ] = document.getElementById( 'Claim'  ) ;
  aTab[ 3 ] = document.getElementById( 'New'    ) ;

  //====== Day ==========================================
  oDayDate = document.getElementById( 'DayDate' ) ;
}

//=====================================================
//====== Main Page ====================================
//=====================================================
function Flip( nTab )
{
  if ( nCur != nTab )
  {
    //  Set New Button To Active & Show New Tab
    aBtn[ nTab ].className = 'CurBttn' ;
    aTab[ nTab ].style.display = 'inline' ;

    //  Set Previous Button To Inactive & Hide Previous Tab
    aBtn[ nCur ].className = 'TabBttn' ;
    aTab[ nCur ].style.display = 'none' ;

    nCur = nTab ;
  }
}

//=====================================================
//====== Months =======================================
//=====================================================
function ShowDay( oDay, sDate )
{
  if ( oMonthCurDay != oDay )
  {
    if ( null != oMonthCurDay )
    {
      oMonthCurDay.className = sMonthCurDay ; 
    }

    oMonthCurDay = oDay ;
    sMonthCurDay = oDay.className ;
    oDay.className = 'Cell Open' ;
  }

  Flip( 1 ) ;
  SetDay( sDate ) ;
}

//=====================================================
//====== Day ==========================================
//=====================================================
function SetDay( sDate )
{
  var sYr = sDate.slice(0,4) ;
  var sMn = ( sDate.slice(4,6) ) ;
  var sDy = sDate.slice(-2) ;

  oDayDate.innerHTML = sYr+' '+sMn+' '+sDy
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="ClientForm" action="" method="post" > <!-- Action & Method Are There For Strict Validation Purposes Only.  Form Is Never To Be Submitted! -->
      <div style="padding: 0 5px; 0; " >
        <div style="clear: both; padding: 6px 0 8px 16px; " >
          <button type="button" class="CurBttn" id="Bttn0" onclick="Flip( 0 );" >Months</button>
          <button type="button" class="TabBttn" id="Bttn1" onclick="Flip( 1 );" >Days</button>
        </div>
        <div class="Tab" id="Months" >
          <div class="CalendarDIV" >
            <div class="Mnth" >November</div>
            <div class="Cell Head" >S</div><div class="Cell Head" >M</div><div class="Cell Head" >T</div><div class="Cell Head" >W</div><div class="Cell Head" >T</div><div class="Cell Head" >F</div><div class="Cell Head" >S</div>
            <div class="Cell Not Clr" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div id="Date20131101" class="Cell Day" onclick="ShowDay( this, '20131101' );" >1</div>
            <div id="Date20131102" class="Cell Day" onclick="ShowDay( this, '20131102' );" >2</div>
            <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both; height: 8px; " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Tab" id="Day" style="display: none; " >
          <div style="float: left; padding: 0 6px 0 0;">
            <div id="DayDate" style="padding: 0 0 6px 50px; " >
              &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="Doctor" style="background-color: #DBFFFF; " >
              Dr. Finger
            </div>
            <div class="Hours" >
              <div class="Slot0" >
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:00</div><div class="Info" >Claim # - Last, First</div></div>
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:15</div></div>
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:30</div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Second Code Example:

```
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
/*************************************************************************
******** Page ************************************************************
*************************************************************************/
.Tab
{
  position: relative;
}
.TabBttn
{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #4DCBEF;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left ;
}
.TabBttn:hover
{
  background-color: #85FFD6;
}
.TabBttn:focus
{
  background-color: #85FFD6;
}
.CurBttn
{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #EBF0FA;
  color: #470047;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left ;
}
#C_Debug
{
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
  max-height: 800px;
  padding: 6px 12px 0 0;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: none;
}

/*************************************************************************
******** Month ***********************************************************
*************************************************************************/
.CalendarDIV
{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
.Mnth
{
  background-color: #6699FF;
  color: #000;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Cell
{
  float: left; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 53px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
}
.Head
{
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Clr
{
  clear: both;
}
.Day
{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000 ;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Not
{
  background-color: #DCE0E0;
}
.Today
{
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.First
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #005CE6;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Last
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #007A00;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Open
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #FFFF99;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Closed
{
  border-color: silver;
  background-color: #FF9999;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
//====== Main Page ====================================
var aBtn = new Array() ;
var aTab = new Array() ;
var nCur = 0 ;

//====== Day ==========================================
var oMonthCurDay = null ;
var sMonthCurDay = null ;

//====== Day ==========================================
var oDayDate = null ;

window.onload = function ()
{
  //====== Main Page ====================================
  aBtn[ 0 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn0'  ) ; 
  aBtn[ 1 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn1'  ) ;
  aBtn[ 2 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn2'  ) ;
  aBtn[ 3 ] = document.getElementById( 'Bttn3'  ) ;
  aTab[ 0 ] = document.getElementById( 'Months' ) ; 
  aTab[ 1 ] = document.getElementById( 'Day'    ) ;
  aTab[ 2 ] = document.getElementById( 'Claim'  ) ;
  aTab[ 3 ] = document.getElementById( 'New'    ) ;

  //====== Day ==========================================
  oDayDate = document.getElementById( 'DayDate' ) ;
}

//=====================================================
//====== Main Page ====================================
//=====================================================
function Flip( nTab )
{
  if ( nCur != nTab )
  {
    //  Set New Button To Active & Show New Tab
    aBtn[ nTab ].className = 'CurBttn' ;
    //aTab[ nTab ].style.display = 'inline' ;

    //  Set Previous Button To Inactive & Hide Previous Tab
    aBtn[ nCur ].className = 'TabBttn' ;
    //aTab[ nCur ].style.display = 'none' ;

    nCur = nTab ;
  }
}

//=====================================================
//====== Months =======================================
//=====================================================
function ShowDay( oDay, sDate )
{
  if ( oMonthCurDay != oDay )
  {
    if ( null != oMonthCurDay )
    {
      oMonthCurDay.className = sMonthCurDay ; 
    }

    oMonthCurDay = oDay ;
    sMonthCurDay = oDay.className ;
    oDay.className = 'Cell Open' ;
  }

  Flip( 1 ) ;
  SetDay( sDate ) ;
}

//=====================================================
//====== Day ==========================================
//=====================================================
function SetDay( sDate )
{
  var sYr = sDate.slice(0,4) ;
  var sMn = ( sDate.slice(4,6) ) ;
  var sDy = sDate.slice(-2) ;

  oDayDate.innerHTML = sYr+' '+sMn+' '+sDy
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="ClientForm" action="" method="post" > <!-- Action & Method Are There For Strict Validation Purposes Only.  Form Is Never To Be Submitted! -->
      <div style="padding: 0 5px; 0; " >
        <div style="clear: both; padding: 6px 0 8px 16px; " >
          <button type="button" class="CurBttn" id="Bttn0" onclick="Flip( 0 );" >Months</button>
          <button type="button" class="TabBttn" id="Bttn1" onclick="Flip( 1 );" >Days</button>
        </div>
        <div class="Tab" id="Months" >
          <div class="CalendarDIV" >
            <div class="Mnth" >November</div>
            <div class="Cell Head" >S</div><div class="Cell Head" >M</div><div class="Cell Head" >T</div><div class="Cell Head" >W</div><div class="Cell Head" >T</div><div class="Cell Head" >F</div><div class="Cell Head" >S</div>
            <div class="Cell Not Clr" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div class="Cell Not" ></div>
            <div id="Date20131101" class="Cell Day" onclick="ShowDay( this, '20131101' );" >1</div>
            <div id="Date20131102" class="Cell Day" onclick="ShowDay( this, '20131102' );" >2</div>
            <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both; height: 8px; " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Tab" id="Day" > <!-- style="display: none; " -->
          <div style="float: left; padding: 0 6px 0 0;">
            <div id="DayDate" style="padding: 0 0 6px 50px; " >
              &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="Doctor" style="background-color: #DBFFFF; " >
              Dr. Finger
            </div>
            <div class="Hours" >
              <div class="Slot0" >
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:00</div><div class="Info" >Claim # - Last, First</div></div>
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:15</div></div>
                <div class="Qrtr" ><div class="Time" >07:30</div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Thank You..

Comment: I don't understand you question and your code examples are identical...

Comment: The Two Examples are different in the way I stated when I posted the question.  In the Javascript, the function Flip has the two lines the hide and show the DIVs are commented out in the second example.  And in the second example the DIVs are both not set to "Display: none;".

If you run each example, you will find that in the first example, when a day is picked on the Calendar and the Month DIV is hidden and none of the DIVs with then process onclick once you go back to the Month DIV.

Where as in the second exmaple, because the Month DIV is never hidden, the DIVs onclick events stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation :
 write your functions code inside :

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click",function(e) {    

//your code here 

});
```

Check for detail : [link](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: This is Dynamic code...  there would be a minimum of 60 eventlisteners to add...  and then to remove if months change... all changes performed with AJAX... not a page reload.  Not a good solution.